# Wpf Validation rule force update

Tags: wpf, validationrules

I'm have a hard time trying how to figure out a problem with a validation Rule, I have a datagrid with some columns, and the columns can't have a same value in different rows, I can display a error in one of the duplicate rows, but the problem is, if I fix the row which has no error, the row with error continue with a red border, someone might know if there is a way to when I change a cell value, a force a validation update in all the rows of my datagrid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What validation mechanism are you using?  If you use `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, you can fire an event telling the grid that the validation errors for the entire item/row have changed, but that requires the client to have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: Actually I'm inheriting from ValidationRule.